# How to post data received from the server onto the client website

Tags: html, angular

I receive the following data from the server to the client and is stored in res variable:

```
0: {date: "2014-12-02T00:00:00", close: 106.9064, buySell: "Sell"}
1: {date: "2014-12-03T00:00:00", close: 108.1188, buySell: "Sell"}
2: {date: "2014-12-04T00:00:00", close: 107.7084, buySell: "Sell"}
```

This is the angular code that prints the above to the console window:

```
  getBuySellData(){
     this.http.get(this.stockURL).subscribe(res => {
     console.log(res)
})
```

I want to print this data to the client screen.  This is what I am trying now:

```
 <mat-list >
      {{stock}}
 </mat-list>
```

This gets printed on the client website:

```
[object Object]
```

here are the components:

```
export class ApiService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

stock: StockComponent
list: any[]
stockURL = 'https://localhost:44310/api/stock'

/** POST: */
postStock (stock) {
  this.http.post(this.stockURL, stock).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
}

getBuySellData() {
  this.http.get(this.stockURL).subscribe(res => {
    this.stock = res;
  })
}
```

Stocks Component

```
@Component({
selector: 'stocks',
templateUrl: './stocks.component.html' 
})
export class StocksComponent {
  stock = {}
constructor(private api: ApiService){

}

ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getBuySellData()
}

post(stock){
     this.api.postStock(stock)
}
```

Stock Component

```
@Component({
selector: 'stock',
templateUrl: './stock.component.html' 
})
export class StockComponent {
 stock = {}
  constructor(private api: ApiService){
  }

ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getBuySellData()
}

post(stock){

    this.api.postStock(stock)
}
```

Stocks HTML

```
                <mat-list>
                    {{stock.date}}
                  </mat-list>
            <mat-list>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of stock">
                    {{item.date | date}}
                </mat-list-item>
             </mat-list>
```

Comment: Where are you populating `stock` ? and probably you can use `{{stock | json}}` for debugging! (but that's not how you should show). And I didn't downvote!

Comment: xyz, thanks for your comment and not down voting me.  I am learning angular with the help of the online community.  There is a lot I just do not know.

Comment: @Jam66125 does the posted answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you declared `stock`? you should probably assign the content of the response to `stock` like this:

```
getBuySellData() {
  this.http.get(this.stockURL).subscribe(res => {
    this.stock = res;
  })
}
```

And in your template:

```
<mat-list>
  {{stock.date}}
</mat-list>
```

And if you want to format the date output you could use a pipe:

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of stock">
        {{item.date | date}}
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

---

Ok, I think I see the problem now. You should always remember that from within the template you can only access properties declared in the same component. It should be something like this:

Api Service

```js
export class ApiService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

stock: StockComponent
list: any[]
stockURL = 'https://localhost:44310/api/stock'

/** POST: */
postStock (stock) {
  this.http.post(this.stockURL, stock).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
}

getBuySellData() {
  return this.http.get(this.stockURL)
}
```

Stocks Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'stocks',
  templateUrl: './stocks.component.html'
})
export class StocksComponent {
  stock = [];
  constructor(private api: ApiService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getBuySellData().subscribe(res => {
      this.stock = res;
    })
  }

  post(stock) {
    this.api.postStock(stock)
  }
```

stocks.component.html

```html
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of stock">
    {{item.date | date}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: `stock` will be an array, he won't be able to access it like an Object, you need to loop over to get the dates

Comment: You're right! I missed that! sorry!

It should be like this:

<mat-list *ngFor="let item of stock">
  {{item.date | date}}
</mat-list>

Comment: Nicolas, I appreciate your response and time.  I defined stock in stock.component.ts file as "  export class StockComponent {
    stock = {}
      constructor(private api: ApiService){
      }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.api.getBuySellData()
  }"

After I added "                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of stocks">
                    {{item.date | date}}
                </mat-list-item>"

I do not get a response on the client site.  Before with just "stocks' in the html file I got "object Object"

I do not know what I am missing

Comment: could you post all the files involved in this case? with all the relevant pieces of the code please. 

P.S.: I supose you've figured this out already, but in your previous comment you declared `stock` and tried to access `stocks`

Comment: Nicolas, you rule.  I get the data in the client window!  I have another issue though.  when I use "stock = [ ], I get a syntax error.  I changed it to 'stock = { } and the syntax error goes away.  I get the data in the window.  I will open a new question.  You have no idea how much time I have spent on this, over a week.  I was almost ready to pull all of my hair out.  This is my first app and I am excited.  I purchased a domain for the company with to o's in its name and find out they give you server space too!  Thanks for helping me out here.  Totally appreciate it.

Comment: I found out using 'stock' alone I do not get the error. no need for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
First edit your TypeScript logic by assigning your result to a member list.

```
list: any[];
getBuySellData(){
     this.http.get(this.stockURL).subscribe(res => {
     this.list = res;
})
```

Then, in your template, make sure you use the **async** pipe in order to inform Angular that the data you are trying to display is coming in an asynchronous manner, due to observable used.

The implementation might slightly differ, i have not tested it, but the core thing to remember, for erasing that ugly *[object Object]* is the usage of **async** pipe.

```
<mat-list>
   <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of list">
    {{item | async}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```